# AngularStrap $popover not working with ui calendar (wrapper of Fullcalendar)

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-strap

i have a question about how to use AngularStrap's popover with Fullcalendar.
I have this:

```
angular.module('calendarModule', [
        'ui.calendar', 
        'ui.bootstrap', 
        'mgcrea.ngStrap'])
    .controller('CalendarCtrl', function($scope,$compile,$popover,uiCalendarConfig)
```

as module declaration where I will use the popover.

When I try to use something like the aswered here: [Using $popover service in Angular with Fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940245/using-popover-service-in-angular-with-fullcalendar)

I have the console error:

```
"Error: $popover is not a function
```

sigh, aditionally, when in add the bs-popover directive like shown in the question that i reference, i have the next error:

```
"Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [bsPopover, uiCalendar] asking for new/isolated scope on: <div class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" bs-popover="" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar">
```

Loading sequence:

```
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>                       <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>                        <!-- jQuery UI -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.1.2/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.1.2/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>                       <!-- Angular routing -->
        <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.js"></script>                             <!-- Bootstrap UI -->



        <!-- Load JS from local -->

        <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>                                                              <!-- bootstrap -->

        <script src='js/vendor/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>                                                <!-- calendar moment -->
        <!--script src='js/vendor/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>                                             <!- - jquery -->
        <script src='js/vendor/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>                                                  <!-- fullcalendar -->
        <script src='js/vendor/fullcalendar/lang/es.js'></script>                                                       <!-- fullcalendar esp-->
```

like in virtual cop: somebody help me :(

Comment: Can you provide your js loading sequence? jquery needs to be loaded before bootstrap. If you provide your js loading sequence, it will help

Comment: okay buddy, there it is

Answer (score 1):

You have to piggy back off the fullcalendar events. For ex, I use 'select' and 'eventClick' like so:

```
        //clicking the day(empty spot) in the calendar
        select: function(start, end, allDay, el, view) {
            var element = $(el.target);
            popover =  $popover(element, _.extend({
                container: element.parent(),
                html: true,
                template: 'directives/assignment-popover/add-assignment.tpl.html',
                animation: 'am-fade-and-slide-top',
                customClass: 'popover add blue',
                autoClose: 'true'
            }));
            popover.$scope.assignment = {};
            popover.$scope.assignment.due = start;
            popover.$promise.then(popover.show);
        },
```

And when you want to pass data to the popover scope:

```
        //clicking on an event
        eventclick: function( event, el, view ){
            var element = $(el.target).closest('.fc-event');
            popover =  $popover(element, _.extend({
                container: element.parent(),
                html: true,
                template: 'partials/add-assignment.tpl.html',
                animation: 'am-fade-and-slide-top',
                customClass: 'popover add blue',
                autoClose: 'true'
            }));

            //here is the magic ....
            popover.$scope.assignment = event;
            popover.$promise.then(popover.show);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

doyou are injecting $popover service in CalendarCtrl, that's fine.

But you are adding $popover as parameter, this is wrong.

By default, you will have only three parameters in your hover event handler. 
(1) Event
(2) jQueryEvent
(3) View.

So $popover is undefined at your function level. That's why its creating issue.

Change your event hover function to following :

```
$scope.alertOnEventHover = function(event, jsEvent, view){
    var myPopover = $popover(angular.element(jsEvent.target), {
        title: 'My Title',
        content:'My Content',
        show: true,
        trigger: 'hover',
        autoClose: true
    });
};
```

Your second solution will not work, because you are trying to create two isolated scope on single directive. It is not allowed in angular.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: yes and no :/ now is an error -> Error: t[0] is undefined, ponting the line where is -> var myPopover = $popover(jsEvent.target, {

Comment: now is happening some weirdo D: additionally to: "Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context. it shows only if i click in the title of the event, however, the popover shows, BUT only inside the event, and veeeeeeeeeryy small

Comment: pass trigger as 'hover' to show on hover. and autoClose to true.

Comment: sorry man, this remains D: another one Error: t[0].nodeName is undefined but this error only reference code lines of angular and angular-strap